# FileNotFoundException when deploying in local Oracle WebLogic

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, ear

I need to create a local environment to deploy an EAR, which is currently in production.

By documentation, it needs:

- Java EE 7
- Oracle WebLogic 12.1.2
- Maven

Installed everything fine and configured, but this is my first time with Java Enterprise and WebLogic. I downloaded WebLogic from the official website (the 12.1.3 version, which is the only one available for a development installation). Executed all scripts to create a local domain, realm and server. It starts fine.

So, I proceeded generating the EAR within the source code, using `mvn ear:ear` and created the package.

Connected to `localhost:7001/console` and logged in, went into the Deployments Control page and clicked in `install` button. Browsed the EAR and deployed without changing any default configuration. It leads me to an error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [env.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

I thought it was a file missing inside the EAR package, but I opened it with both Eclipse and WinRAR and the `env.properties` file is present, in the right path. So I tried deploying the EAR package that is currently in production, but it still gives this error.

At this point, I think it's some WebLogic configurations I missed. Am I right? Where should I eventually check?

I can NOT share any code snippet, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We still have to understand if it's like this by choice, but the `WAR` file inside the `EAR` actually didn't have the `properties` file. It was sufficient opening it with `WinRAR`, put the file in the right path and re-deploy it.

So, just to say, WebLogic had no missing configurations. The downloadable development package seems to have everything configured.